# Best practice to define implicit/explicit encoding in dataframe column value extraction without RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get column data in a collection without RDD map api (doing the pure dataframe way)

```
object CommonObject{
    def doSomething(...){
        .......
        val releaseDate = tableDF.where(tableDF("item") <=> "releaseDate").select("value").map(r => r.getString(0)).collect.toList.head
    }
}
```

this is all good except Spark 2.3 suggests

```
No implicits found for parameter evidence$6: Encoder[String]
```

between `map` and `collect`

```
map(r => r.getString(0))(...).collect
```

I understand to add

```
import spark.implicits._
```

before the process however it requires a `spark session` instance

it's pretty annoying especially when there is no spark session instance in a method. As a Spark newbie how to nicely resolve the implicit encoding parameter in the context?

Comment: You may do this: `def doSomething(...)(implicit ev: Encoder[String])` Now the responsibility of having such implicit encoder is of the caller. If the caller is on the scope of the `import spark.impkicits._` then all is ready, if not, then the caller must also ask for such implicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add a call to `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` inside your method. Spark will find the already existing SparkSession and won't create a new one, so there is no performance impact. Then you can import explicits which will work for all case classes. This is easiest way to add encoding. Alternatively an explicit encoder can be added using `Encoders` class.

```
    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("name")
      .master("local[2]")
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
```

The other way is to get SparkSession from the dataframe `dataframe.sparkSession`

```
    def dummy (df : DataFrame) = {
    val spark = df.sparkSession
    import spark.implicits._
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why it is down voted. This is correct working code. Can someone please review and upvote it.

Comment: thanks I tried and it works. Sorry for the late feedback